# How do I pull the list of users and their email addresses and export to a file?

Tags: powershell

I started with what I have below.

```
$user = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity mygroup

foreach ($n in $user) {
    (Get-ADUser $n -Properties mail).mail
}
```

Comment: `Get-ADUser ... | Add-Content ...`

Comment: Is that how our script look in real life? You are passing nothing to `add-content`. _but I'm hitting an issue with the add-content._ is not descriptive

Comment: add-content is asking me for another variable. It should just add more email addresses to the list.

Comment: @user770022 You are getting that because you weren't providing `Add-Content` any information when you had it on the separate line. You could pipe information in like this: `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity mygroup | % {(Get-ADUser $_ -Properties mail).mail} | Add-Content c:\user.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked and gave me what I wanted

```
$user = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity mygroup

foreach ($n in $user) {
    (Get-ADUser $n -Properties mail).mail | Add-Content c:\mygroup.txt
}
```